# fix the items in a rank_list so they can be repeated in another rank_list. sortable shiny

Tags: r, shiny, sortablejs

Using the `sortable` package, I'm trying to get fixed the items from a `rank_list` so I can drop an item multiple times to another `rank_list`.

Just like in the field list of a pivot table in Excel where you can add multiple times a column to any of the other sets (rows, columns, values, filters).

I know there is an `options` argument in the `rank_list` that could do the job, but I dont know how I cloud use it. Is it possible to achieve what I want to do?

Thank you.

Here is some code using the `sortable` package.

```
 


library(shiny)
library(sortable)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".bucket-list-container {min-height: 350px;}"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      tags$b("Exercise"),
      width = 12,
      bucket_list(
        header = "Drag the items in any desired bucket",
        group_name = "bucket_list_group",
        orientation = "horizontal",
        add_rank_list(
          text = "Drag from here",
          labels = list(
            "a", "b", "c"
          ),
          input_id = "rank_list_1"
        ),
        add_rank_list(
          text = "to here",
          labels = NULL,
          input_id = "rank_list_2"
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      tags$b("Result"),
      column(
        width = 12,
        
        tags$p("input$rank_list_1"),
        verbatimTextOutput("results_1"),
        
        tags$p("input$rank_list_2"),
        verbatimTextOutput("results_2"),
        
        tags$p("input$bucket_list_group"),
        verbatimTextOutput("results_3")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  output$results_1 <-
    renderPrint(
      input$rank_list_1 # This matches the input_id of the first rank list
    )
  output$results_2 <-
    renderPrint(
      input$rank_list_2 # This matches the input_id of the second rank list
    )
  output$results_3 <-
    renderPrint(
      input$bucket_list_group # Matches the group_name of the bucket list
    )
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, If you were looking for it a vote would be apreciated.

here is the example:

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
      column( 
        width = 6,
      uiOutput("main_rank")
      ),
      column( width =6,
      rank_list(
        text = "X",
        labels = c(),
        input_id = "other_rank",
        options = sortable_options(group = "my_shared_group"))
      )
      
    
  ) 
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  
  # Fixed Items as reactive
  rankvars = reactive({
    
    # Fixed Items
    fixedItems = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
    
    # used 
    used = c()
    used = c(unique(input$other_rank))
    
    # refill the list with unique items
    unique(c(setdiff(fixedItems, used),used))
  })
  
  # Make the main rank as a reactive object
  output$main_rank = renderUI({
    fluidRow(
    rank_list(
      text = "Campos",
      labels = rankvars(), #colnames(Memory$data), #sample(paste0("list item ", 1:5)),
      input_id = "main_list",
      # be sure to have the same group name
      options = sortable_options(group = "my_shared_group")
      ) 
  
    )
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```