# Set default value in a "destination" sortable rank_list group in R Shiny App

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, sortablejs

I am using the R package `sortable` in a Shiny App in a similar way as described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72481552/fix-the-items-in-a-rank-list-so-they-can-be-repeated-in-another-rank-list-sorta), with the aim of drag-and-dropping values from one "source" `rank_list` to a "destination" `rank_list`.

I am facing the following issue : when the app starts, I would like the "destination" `rank_list` to be already filled with one of the value of the "source" `rank_list`. This means for the example here below that when the app starts the "Destination" box on the right already contains e.g. the "b" value.

Is it possible to achieve this ? How ? I guess there is probably a js solution, but I am really a newbie...

Thanks in advance for any help

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    column( 
      width = 6,
      uiOutput("main_rank")
    ),
    column( width =6,
            rank_list(
              text = "Destination",
              labels = c(),
              input_id = "other_rank",
              options = sortable_options(group = "my_shared_group"))
    )
    
    
  ) 
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  
  # Fixed Items as reactive
  rankvars = reactive({
    
    # Fixed Items
    fixedItems = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
    
    # used 
    used = c()
    used = c(unique(input$other_rank))
    
    # refill the list with unique items
    unique(c(setdiff(fixedItems, used),used))
  })
  
  # Make the main rank as a reactive object
  output$main_rank = renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      rank_list(
        text = "Source",
        labels = rankvars(), #colnames(Memory$data), #sample(paste0("list item ", 1:5)),
        input_id = "main_list",
        # be sure to have the same group name
        options = sortable_options(group = "my_shared_group")
      ) 
      
    )
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR I added a new solution and the one you asked for.

In my opinion, the original question misleads you as there is a bucket function in the sortable package designed for such usage.

The example but with `sortable::bucket_list`

```r
library(shiny)
library(sortable)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    column( width = 12,
            bucket_list(
              header = "Drag the items in any desired bucket",
              group_name = "bucket_list_group",
              orientation = "horizontal",
              add_rank_list(
                text = "Drag from here",
                labels = list(
                  "a",
                  "b",
                  "c",
                  "d"
                ),
                input_id = "rank_list_1"
              ),
              add_rank_list(
                text = "to here",
                labels = list("e"),
                input_id = "rank_list_2"
              )
            )
    )
    
    
  ) 
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  
  # Fixed Items as reactive
  rankvars = reactive({
    
    # Fixed Items
    fixedItems = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
    
    # used 
    used = c()
    used = c(unique(input$other_rank))
    
    # refill the list with unique items
    unique(c(setdiff(fixedItems, used),used))
  })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

JS code to add an e element. The idea is to manually add a div with the rank-list-item class when the container is there.

```r
library(shiny)
library(sortable)


ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(
    column( 
      width = 6,
      uiOutput("main_rank")
    ),
    column( width =6,
            rank_list(
              text = "Destination",
              labels = c(),
              input_id = "other_rank",
              options = sortable_options(group = "my_shared_group"))
    )
    
    
  ) 
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  
  # Fixed Items as reactive
  rankvars = reactive({
    # Fixed Items
    fixedItems = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
    
    # used 
    used = c()
    used = c(unique(input$other_rank))
    
    # refill the list with unique items
    unique(c(setdiff(fixedItems, used),used))
  })
  
  # Make the main rank as a reactive object
  output$main_rank = renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      rank_list(
        text = "Source",
        labels = rankvars(), #colnames(Memory$data), #sample(paste0("list item ", 1:5)),
        input_id = "main_list",
        # be sure to have the same group name
        options = sortable_options(group = "my_shared_group")
      ) 
      
    )
    
  })
  
  shiny::observeEvent(input$other_rank, {
    shinyjs::runjs('$("#other_rank").append("<div class=\'rank-list-item\'>e</div>")')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```